# Solution to a particular quadratic matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for the solution of the following quadratic matrix equation

$XAX^{\prime }-XB+A=\mathbf{0}$

where $A$, $B$ and $X$ are square matrices and $B$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Could you edit your post to include some of your thoughts?

Comment: How about you try a simple case. Say $A=0$ (i.e. the all zero matrix)? Then try $B=0$. And can try smaller $2x2$ examples as well.

Comment: Are the matrices real or complex? Which ones are the unknowns? What is $X'$?

Comment: Try re-writing the equation as an iteration, e.g.
$$X_{k+1} = A\left(B-AX_{k}^T\right)^{-1}$$
whose convergence depends on $A,B,$ and the initial guess $X_0$

Comment: Perhaps diagonalize A to $UDU^{-1}$ and replace XU by Y?

Comment: @greg Thank you. Your suggestion works. I was hoping to get something in close form though.

Answer (score 2):

In the special case where $A$ is Hermitian and $-B\preceq 2A\preceq B$, the equation can be solved as follows. Since $B\succ0$ and $A$ is Hermitian, the two matrices can be simultaneously diagonalised by congruence. More specifically, let $UDU^\ast$ be a unitary diagonalisation of $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. (If both $A$ and $B$ are real, $U$ and in turn $P$ can be taken to be real.) Then $B=PP^\ast$ and $A=PDP^\ast$, where $P=B^{1/2}U$. So, if we put $Y=P^{-1}XP$, the equation in question can be rewritten as
$$
YDY^\ast - Y + D = 0.\tag{1}
$$
As $-B\preceq 2A\preceq B$, we have $-I\preceq 2B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}\preceq I$, i.e. $-I\preceq 2D\preceq I$. Therefore $|2d_{ii}|\le1$ for each $i$ and we may take $Y$ to be a real diagonal matrix such that
$$
y_{ii}=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }d_{ii}=0,\\
\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4d_{ii}^2}}{2}&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence $X=PYP^{-1}$ solves the original equation.

Comment: Well-done, ***+1, endorsed!*** However, you assume $A$ is non-singular, which is not given in the problem.  Any ideas about that case?   Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Ugh. I've misread the question. I thought $A$ was positive definite.

Comment: Still nice work though.  You might just add a line saying you are dealing with a special case  . .

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure this works.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure this works. I have tried, e.g., with $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.05 &  0.07 \\ 0.02 & 0.04 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0.97 &  0.07 \\ 0.07 & 0.97 \end{bmatrix}$ and I get $X = \begin{bmatrix} 0.035 &  0.004 \\ 0.001 & 0.003 \end{bmatrix}$. With this I get that $XAX'-XB+A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.0466  &  0.0693 \\ 0.0197  & -0.0433 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @ivan As said in the first sentence, this answer only deals with the special case where $A$ is Hermitian and $-B\preceq 2A\preceq B$. The $A$ in your example isn't Hermitian.